# display data from multiple tables using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables

```
tblData
ID Name
1  ABC
2  XYZ

tblDetails  
ID DataID PayDate     Amount ApprovedDate
1  1      15-08-2015  200    20-18-2015 
2  1      16-08-2015  300    20-18-2015
3  1      17-08-2015  50     20-18-2015 
4  2      18-08-2015  100    21-18-2015   
5  2      19-08-2015  500    21-18-2015
```

I need to get the result like the following

```
ID          Duration                TotalAmount ApprovedDate 
1   15-08-2015 - 17-08-2015         550         20-18-2015  
2   18-08-2015 - 19-08-2015         600         21-18-2015
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: How does `tblData` fit in?

Comment: `SELECT somecolumn, AGGREGATEVALUEOF(someothercolumn), ANOTHER_AGGREGATE_VALUE_OF(another_column), AND_YET_ANOTHER_AGGREGATEVALUE_OF(yet_another_column) FROM some_table GROUP BY somecolumn;`

Comment: Hi Stuart, the DataID comes from tblData.ID - somestimes we need to show  the respective records from tblDetails, related to ID from tblData.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like a simple `GROUP BY` together with some aggregate functions can do the job:

```
SELECT DataID, CONCAT(MIN(PayDate), ' - ', MAX(PayDAte)) AS  Duration,
       SUM(Amount) AS TotalAmount, MAX(ApprovedDate) AS ApprovedDate 
FROM tblDetails
GROUP BY DataID
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/19bb62/2)

Note: Table `tblData` does not seem to play any role in producing the required result set.

Comment: @Strawberry Excuse me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use joins in your query which will join data from different tables into one. [Simple example](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Comment: There are no joins required here. All the info is in the second table.

Comment: a simple join will not produce the desired result set as stated in the question.